# Error in fs.readFileSync() in nodejs

Tags: node.js, filesystems, fs

I am calling a sync call using **require('fs');** in **nodejs**

```
var folder_path = '/home/abc';
var myfiles = ['a.png','b.png'];
_.each(myfiles, function(name){
    var data = fs.readFileSync(folder_path+'/'+name);
    if(data){
       // Some operation
    }
});
```

while calling that function i'm getting **Error: EISDIR, illegal operation on a directory**

```
fs.js:488
  var r = binding.read(fd, buffer, offset, length, position);
              ^
Error: EISDIR, illegal operation on a directory
at Object.fs.readSync (fs.js:488:19)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:322:28)
at /home/coader/dev/api/controllers/MyController.js:66:30
at Function.forEach ( /home/coader/dev/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:3298:15)
at /home/coader/dev/api/controllers/MyController.js:41:11
at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
```

Details

```
$ node -v
v0.10.37

$ nodejs -v
v0.10.37

$ npm -v
1.4.28
```

Any answer will be appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you call `each` on `_` and not `myfiles`?

Comment: No specific reason ... I have used underscore.js so i called _.each().

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to settle for "myfiles.forEach(function(name)"

```
var folder_path = '/home/abc';
var myfiles = ['a.png','b.png'];
myfiles.forEach(function(name){
    var data = fs.readFileSync(folder_path+'/'+name);
    if(data){
             // Some operation
            }
});
```

Comment: is this work? I have similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608118/uncaught-typeerror-fs-readfilesync-is-not-a-function