# Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function

Tags: meteor, reactjs, webpack, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to get webpack and [mapbox-gl](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/master/webpack.config.example.js) work together within Meteor system. I have look everywhere about the error mentioned above but none works. Here is my webpack setup

```
{
  "root": "src",
  "devServer": {
    "host": "localhost"
  },
  "sass": {
    "module": true
  },
  "css": {
    "module": true
  },
  "node": {
    "fs": "empty"
  },
  "externals": {
    "fs": "{}",
    "tls": "{}",
    "net": "{}",
    "console": "{}"
  },
  "module": {
    "loaders": [
      { 
        "test": "/\\.js$/", 
        "include": "./node_modules/mapbox-gl/js/render/painter/use_program.js", 
        "loader": "transform/cacheable?brfs"
      }, {
        "test": "/\\.js$/",
        "include": "./node_modules/mapbox-gl-shaders/index.js",
        "loader": "transform/cacheable?brfs"
      }, {
        "test": "/\\.js$/",
        "include": "./node_modules/webworkify-webpack/index.js",
        "loader": "worker"
      }, {
        "test": "/\\.css$/",
        "loader": "style!css?importLoaders=1!autoprefixer",
        "include": [
            "./node_modules"
        ]
      }, {
        "test": "/\\.scss$/",
        "include": [
          "./node_modules"
        ]
      }, {
        "test": "/\\.sass$/",
        "loader": "!style!css!sass?indentedSyntax!",
        "include": [
          "./node_modules"
        ]
      }, { 
        "test": "/\\.json$/", 
        "loader": "json-loader" 
      }, { 
        "test": "/\\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/", 
        "loader": "url-loader" 
      }
    ]
  },
  "postcss": [ "autoprefixer({ browsers: [last 2 versions'] })" ],
  "postLoaders": [
    {
      "include": "./node_modules/mapbox-gl/",
      "loader": "transform",
      "query": "brfs"
    }
  ],
  "resolve": {
    "alias": {
      "webworkify": "webworkify-webpack"
    }
  }
}
```

For your information, I use webpack provided by the [Reactive Stack](https://github.com/thereactivestack/meteor-webpack) and the way it setup the webpack slightly different.

and here is my `package.json` for the npm setup

```
"dependencies": {
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.2.3",
    "meteoredux": "0.0.2",
    "numeral": "^1.5.3",
    "object-assign": "^4.0.1",
    "react": "^0.14.8",
    "react-addons-create-fragment": "^0.14.8",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^0.14.8",
    "react-addons-linked-state-mixin": "^0.14.8",
    "react-addons-perf": "^0.14.8",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^0.14.8",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.8",
    "react-addons-transition-group": "^0.14.8",
    "react-addons-update": "^0.14.8",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.8",
    "react-helmet": "^3.0.0",
    "react-mixin": "^3.0.4",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.4",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^0.2.2",
    "redux": "^3.4.0",
    "string": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.3.26",
    "babel-core": "^6.7.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "brfs": "^1.4.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^0.9.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "geojson": "^0.3.0",
    "less": "^2.3.1",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.3",
    "node-sass": "^3.6.0",
    "react-transform-catch-errors": "^1.0.0",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.1",
    "redbox-react": "^1.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "sass-resources-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.4.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "webworkify-webpack": "^1.1.0",
    "transform-loader": "^0.2.3",
    "mapbox-gl": "^0.19.0"
  }
```

What have I done wrong? Appreciate someone from [MDG](https://www.meteor.com/company) can explain the error because I believe it has something to with Meteor system. FYI, I use `npm start` to run the page

**UPDATE**

Based on suggestion from @also, I move part of my setup to `webpack.conf.js`

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
        alias: {
            webworkify: 'webworkify-webpack'
        }
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: 'json-loader'
        }, {
            test: /\.js$/,
            include: path.resolve('./node_modules/mapbox-gl-shaders/index.js'),
            loader: 'transform/cacheable?brfs'
        }],
        postLoaders: [{
            include: /node_modules\/mapbox-gl-shaders/,
            loader: 'transform',
            query: 'brfs'
        }]
    }
};
```

which I get the setup from [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/master/webpack.config.example.js). And my `webpack.json`

```
{
  "root": "src",
  "devServer": {
    "host": "localhost"
  },
  "sass": {
    "module": true
  },
  "css": {
    "module": true
  },
  "module": {
    "loaders": [
      {
        "test": "/\\.css$/",
        "loader": "style!css?importLoaders=1!autoprefixer",
        "include": [
            "./node_modules",
          "./src/SewApps/client/css",
            "./src/SewApps/client/Search/css"
        ]
      }, {
        "test": "/\\.scss$/",
        "include": [
          "./node_modules",
          "./src/SewApps/client/css",
          "./src/SewApps/client/Search/css"
        ]
      }, {
        "test": "/\\.sass$/",
        "loader": "!style!css!sass?indentedSyntax!",
        "include": [
          "./node_modules"
        ]
      }, { 
        "test": "/\\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/", 
        "loader": "url-loader" 
      }
    ]
  },
  "postcss": [ "autoprefixer({ browsers: [last 2 versions'] })" ]
}
```

but I still hit another error

```
=> Exited with code: 8                        
W20160609-14:26:04.106(8)? (STDERR) 
W20160609-14:26:04.107(8)? (STDERR) /Users/muhaimincs/Documents/soulja/src/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/server.js:59
W20160609-14:26:04.107(8)? (STDERR)     import { ReactRouterSSR } from 'meteor/reactrouter:react-router-ssr';
W20160609-14:26:04.107(8)? (STDERR)     ^^^^^^
W20160609-14:26:04.107(8)? (STDERR) SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
W20160609-14:26:04.107(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/muhaimincs/Documents/suolja/src/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:278:30
W20160609-14:26:04.107(8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20160609-14:26:04.107(8)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/muhaimincs/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.1.r1m70++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20160609-14:26:04.107(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/muhaimincs/Documents/soulja/src/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:133:5
```

Comment: `fs` is a NodeJS module used to access the File System. Are you trying to run this from a browser ?

Comment: No. it's not like that. When I have successfully complete the webpack then this error appear in browser

Comment: Webpack setup does not explain where and why fs.readFileSync is called. If it is called by client code, this is a mistake. I would suggest to debug readFileSync calls and proceed from call stack.

Comment: if I remove the `fs`, then during my build I will have this `ERROR in ./~/mapbox-gl-shaders/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /node_modules/mapbox-gl-shaders
 @ ./~/mapbox-gl-shaders/index.js 1:9-22`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following webpack.config.js is working for me. It incorporates @also's good idea for the brfs matcher:

```js
var webpack = require('webpack')
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: './app.js',
  output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js'],
    alias: {
      webworkify: 'webworkify-webpack',
      'mapbox-gl': path.resolve('./node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js')
    }
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/webworkify/index.js'),
        loader: 'worker'
      },
      {
        test: /mapbox-gl.+\.js$/,
        loader: 'transform/cacheable?brfs'
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

I have a [working example](https://github.com/sleepycat/mapboxgl-webpack-example) that I have been keeping up to date.

Comment: what version of mapboxgl

Comment: I'm running 0.18.0 in my project, and the working example is 0.20.0. Both are working without errors.

Comment: I hit this warning `./~/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js
Critical dependencies:
1:481-488 This seems to be a pre-built javascript file. Though this is possible, it's not recommended. Try to require the original source to get better results.
 @ ./~/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js 1:481-488`

Comment: If you include the source file instead of the prebuilt js you end up with the famous "can't read property 'call' of undefined" error. It will compile fine, but you will see it in the browser. I've decided I can live with the warning. :)

Answer (score 1):

**You're using strings for the `test` and `include` loader options which won't match.** These are [not converted to regular expressions](https://github.com/thereactivestack/meteor-webpack/blob/master/packages/webpack/plugin/WebpackCompiler.js#L90), so things like `js$` will never match–that would mean a literal `$` in the filename. When the condition is a string, it will be [compared against the full path](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders), so `./node_modules/mapbox-gl/js/render/painter/use_program.js` wouldn't match either.

Since the loader conditions aren't being met, the loader isn't running and the `fs.readFileSync` call isn't being inlined by the [`brfs`](https://github.com/substack/brfs) transform.

**To fix this**, it looks like the Reactive Stack Webpack plugin will [read a `webpack.conf.js` file](https://github.com/thereactivestack/meteor-webpack/blob/master/packages/webpack/plugin/WebpackCompiler.js#L55), where you could use actual regular expressions and match all `.js` files or the particular files that need the transform.

For example, in `webpack.conf.js` (note that this file is specific to this Meteor Webpack plugin):

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /mapbox-gl.+\.js$/,
        loader: 'transform/cacheable?brfs'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

This will match all `.js` files with `mapbox-gl` in the path.

I think you'll want to update all your `module.loaders` to use regular expressions. If you need to check if a loader is matching, a quick hack is to change the `loader` to something bogus:

```
      {
        test: /mapbox-gl.+\.js$/,
        loader: 'XXXtransform/cacheable?brfs'
      }
```

If it matches, Webpack will throw an exception when it can't find the loader. On the other hand, if you *don't* see an exception you know you've got a problem with your configuration.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Now I move all my config to `webpack.conf.js`. See my updated question above

Answer (score 0):

This part is redundant:

```
"node": {
  "fs": "empty"
}
```

Not sure if it's causing the problem, but you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Try this:

Identify which module is throwing the `fs.readFileSync` error. For me it was `mime` which is a dependency of `url-loader`.

I replaced it with `file-loader` which doesn't depend on `mime`, and hence not the `fs`. Ensure to uninstall `url-loader` as it will still throw the error!

Then update your `webpack.conf` with:

`{
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|jpg|gif|png|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader' 
      }`

Hope that helps!